# Multiple XML mappings for the same Java object using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

Note: Editing this to rephrase it around JAXB in hopes of getting new answers. I'm using CXF, but it's using JAXB for the mappings.

I've got a POJO model. Right now I have it mapped via annotations and using JAXB to spew/read XML. However that's only one XML format and I need to map that POJO model to one of various XML formats depending on the 3rd party system I'm integrating with (e.g. various 3rd parties all have the concept of a "person", but map it differently). I've read through the entire JAXB tutorial, but everything is centered around annotations. Is there some external way to map the classes so I can read/write multiple mappings where I pick the mapping to use at any given point (i.e. I know I'm spewing a "person" to Foo Inc., so use the foo mapping)?

Edit: I just found something called JAXBIntroductions that might do the job.
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JAXBIntroductions

Comment: Do you need to use all of those XML formats in CXF?

Comment: Ideally, yes :) Simply because I've already mapped my core objects with CXF for a particular XML api. Turns out though I need to be able to map those core Java objects for a new XML API as well and likely many others over time. So, if I could use CXF for all, that'd be great. If not, that's fine I'll use whatever works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) for this. you can work without annotations like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
xstream.alias("phonenumber", PhoneNumber.class);
```

hope that helps

EDIT: create another XStream instance for a different output

```
Person demo = new Person("Chris");

XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("person", Person.class);
System.out.println(xStream.toXML(demo));

XStream xStream2 = new XStream();
xStream2.alias("dev", Person.class);
System.out.println(xStream2.toXML(demo));
```

output:

```
<person>
  <name>Chris</name>
</person>
<dev>
  <name>Chris</name>
</dev>
```

Comment: Does XStream let me customize how it maps? So, can I map the Java Person to <employer> in one mapping, but <employee> in another mapping?

Comment: yes, you can, if you create another XStream instance and configure it accordingly, i'll edit the answer with an example and the output

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'll have to check that out. My mapping needs are going to need quite a bit of flexibility (for instance, some sub-Java objects may need values in the same XML element as the parent. E.g. Address and FullName may be a Java children, but in the XML it's spewed at the same level or as attributes rather than elements).

Comment: MOXy has this type of support, for more information on its XPath based mapping see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: XStream has the obvious disadvantage of being fully proprietary.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) you can take advantage of the externalized mapping feature to apply many XML representations to your POJOs.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML

Also, since MOXy's mappings are XPath based you can actually map your POJOs to a wide variety of XML schemas.

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/SAX2JavaBinding

This is also based on annotations. but annotations are not on your POJO.